# ng serve | -v | any command in ubuntu's terminal is not working, whereas in intellij's local terminal it is working

Tags: node.js, linux, angular, npm, angular-cli

I updated angular cli version to version > 8.0, but then due to some problem I downgraded it back to version 6.2.9 . But now when I try to run any ng command ubuntu terminal would show --> You are running version v8.16.0 of Node.js, which is not supported by Angular CLI 8.0+.
The official Node.js version that is supported is 10.9 or greater.
My angular version is actually 6.2.9 now and node version is 8.16.0 but ng command does not work.

Comment: Please provide your `package.json` file, and the results of the commands `npx ng version` & `ng version`

Comment: both npx ng version and ng version gives same result -->  You are running version v8.16.0 of Node.js, which is not supported by Angular CLI 8.0+. The official Node.js version that is supported is 10.9 or greater. But i tried npm list -g | grep angular/cli --> this gives result as version 6.2.9 @Maryannah

Comment: Well simply upgrade NodeJS, you won't have anymore issues !

Comment: @Maryannah Upgrading nodejs have some problems with node sass files in angular project.

Comment: Having the latest version of node means that it will work if previous versions were used. The opposite is not true though.

Comment: @Maryannah yeah i will need to rebuild my node sass files. But thank you :)